# Angular UI.Sortable cancelling won't redraw original order

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

Im using Angular UI.Sortable for ordering list. In the list, the last element is not generated by ng-repeat and it's manually created. This element is not needed to drag. It should remain the same position after canceling the sort.

Here is my code

```
$scope.sortable = {
                items: '> li.draggable',
                forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                forceHelperSize: true,
                placeholder: 'card-drop-placeholder',
                connectWith: '.cards',
                dropOnEmpty: true,
                tolerance: 'intersect',
                scroll: true,
                scrollSensitivity: 40,
                disabled: false,
                handle: '.handle',
                helper: 'clone',
                cursor: 'move',
                start: onCardStartDrag,
                stop: onCardStopDrag,
                update: onCardStopDragged,
                receive: onDropToAnotherGroup
            };
```

HTML

```
<ul class="cards" ui-sortable="sortable" ng-model="group.cards" group-id="{{ group.groupId }}">
<li ng-repeat="card in group.cards | searchFor : searchText track by $id(card)" ng-class="{'card-with-alerts':card.alert}"
    class="draggable">
    <card-view card="card" status="cardStatus" view="display"></card-view>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="card empty-card">
        <div class="card-container">
            <a href="#" context-menu="false" ng-click="enrollOrCreateCourse($event)">+ {{ enrollText }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

After cancelling the sorting 'empty-card' list element sometimes display at first position of the list.

Cancel logic as follows

```
function onCardStopDragged(e, ui) {
                if ($scope.searchText && $scope.searchText.length > 0) {
                    ui.item.data('position', '-999');
                    ui.item.sortable.cancel();

                    $('#clearFilterConfirmationDialog').modal('show').focus();
                }
            }
```

Comment: try this: http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-sortable-view/#?tab=7

Comment: Unable to use new plugin. Need to fix this issue. Thanks for the information